# How to configure JIRA with ViewVC URLs to view the changes made to repository

Tags: svn, jira

Am having a problem in configuring ViewVC in Jira. Am not able to get the changes as intended in proving the URLs in the configuration. For example:

I have used the following URL for getting the modifications done to a file:

http://hostname/svn/company${path}/?revision=${rev}&r1=${rev}&r2=${rev-1}

The above URL is not giving me the comparision between the current and earlier version of the file.

Please let me know the URLs for:

Changeset Format: 
File Added Format: 
File Modified Format: 
File Replaced Format:

File Deleted Format:

Thanks,

Comment: It seems to me Fisheye is the better choice: https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/FISH/JIRA+FishEye+Plugin

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can subversion do from the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109958/what-can-subversion-do-from-the-browser)